# What word can I use for someone who studies biomimetics? Can I use 'biomimeticist' if that word doesn't exist in the dictionaries?

Tags: single-word-requests

While writing a report and needing to be brief I wondered if I could use a single word to call a subset of researchers dealing with biomimetics (the science of replicating biological solutions in technology). "*People studying biomimetics*" sounds rather cumbersome, so a single-word solution would be very welcome!

Comment: It's certainly used in the literature. I'd say that this is a rare occasion where you can safely anticipate that a word will soon be added to the majority of quality dictionaries. The sub-domain is quite new and still  rather niche and esoteric, so one can understand why mainstream dictionaries haven't picked up on the neologism yet. There's hardly likely to be a problem with ambiguous meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Biomimeticist" is fine. While it's not in any of the dictionaries that I checked either (probably for one or more of the reasons Oxford Dictionaries mentions on their [blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/08/52-words-really-not-included-dictionaries/)), it is a word that people use.

Here are some examples, specifically from scholarly publications:

- > As **biomimeticist** Michael Roggero tells it, living creatures are continually emitting low-level auras of chemical compounds, ‘donating’ small portions of themselves – ourselves – to the environmental media that surrounds them.
  >   <sub>[Reinventing biological life, reinventing ‘the
  >   human’](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/30699150/10-2ephemera-may10.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1507417715&Signature=kMSzPkaYtBINVmO83z48rUFxMfo%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DPirates_and_the_uses_of_history.pdf#page=89)</sub>
- > To the **biomimeticist** this presents a challenge, since technology resorts to over 300 polymers, plus metals, to produce the same range of properties.
  >   <sub>[Biomimetics — a review](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1243/09544119jeim561)</sub>
- > **Biomimeticists** usually fall into two camps: those who use and expand upon the universe of molecules and processes controlling the formation of naturally occurring materials, and those who mimic the structure and function of biomaterials through chemistry and fabrication.
  >   <sub>[Review of Biomimetic and Bioinspired Nanomaterials](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja2018338?journalCode=jacsat)</sub>

If you want more examples, you can search [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=1%2C39&q=%22biomimeticists%22&btnG=) (which returns scholarly articles) or regular [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="biomimeticist").